# Extracting subclip from a .webm file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract a subclip from a `webm` file and write to an `mp4` fil. I have the  following command line:

```
ffmpeg -ss 560 -i input.webm -ss 20 -t 46 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

but I get the following error:

```
ffmpeg version 1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 22 2013 10:42:11 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/path/to/installations --enable-shared --enable-gpl --en
able-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-libx264                           
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/path/to/input.webm':                                          
  Duration: 01:13:20.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2006 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fp,
 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)                                         
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
[mp4 @ 0x1493c340] track 0: could not find tag, codec not currently support
ed in container                                                           
Output #0, mp4, to '/path/to/output.mp4':                         
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-3
1, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 1k tbc (default)                                      
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis ([221][0][0][0] / 0x00DD), 44100 Hz, st
ereo (default)                                                            
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): O
peration not permitted
```

The strange thing is that the following works well for extracting files from `mp4` to `mp4`

```
ffmpeg -ss 560 -i input.mp4 -ss 20 -t 46 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 6):

> ... `codec not currently supported in container`

An MP4 container won't accept VP8 video and Vorbis audio streams (`-acodec copy -vcodec copy`). To test this, change the output filename to `output.mkv` or `output.webm` and the job will work. If the output container must be MP4, you'll need to transcode at some point.

Comment: Thanks! I thought ffmpeg would automatically transcode it if it has to. Do I need to download/build a particular codec to do this? Where I can I find it?

Comment: It _will_ transcode based simply on output filename (though you may want more control than that). Here, the arguments `-acodec copy -vcodec copy` tell ffmpeg _not_ to transcode the video and audio streams (to copy them as-is), so all it tries to do is remux them into an MP4 container, which fails. Remove those arguments and you'll get a result closer to what you expect.